# How to fix Lexical or Preprocessor Issue 'Flutter/Flutter.h' not found

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, dart

I have a flutter app which used to works on iOS, but I changed some code on it and now when I try to run the application in iPad it throws this error:
[image]

I already tried many things, but anything worked.. I runned `pod deintegrate`, `flutter clean`, `pod update`, and can't run the app. Someone could save my week?

Comment: I am facing the same  Lexical or Preprocessor  issue with all of the iOS Pods. did you find the fix.?